# Is there a redaction in John 19:34?

Tags: john

I've read it said that Bultmann argued that the "water and blood" which came out of Jesus in John 19:34 were an "ecclesiastical redaction", and I do not have access to his commentary. Are there others who think this? If so, what are their arguments? What are the arguments against it?

Answer (score 2):

John 19:34 has a parallel in 1 John 5:8, so if there was a redaction it would probably have occurred in both passages. In any case, John 19:32-36 makes quite good sense even without the reference to blood and water.

In the nineteenth century, a number of scholars interpreted the 'blood and water' of this passage as symbolic of a "double cleansing and vivifying power." However, even if the words were intended symbolically, that does not necessarily make them a redaction. Sebastian A. Carnazzo (*[Seeing Blood and Water: A Narrative-Critical Study of John 19:34](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=vV5NAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22blood%20and%20water%22%20redaction&source=bl&ots=D68BsA6CfD&sig=H3NvW2gD_jX9c7SOja9gFtUwEEU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzqsK52bHKAhVHHKYKHSGOAOgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22blood%20and%20water%22%20redaction&f=false)*, pages 5-6) says that Rudolf K. Bultmann argued in 1934 that the 'blood and water' was a later ecclesiastical redaction to the original text. He said that the redactor intended the insertion to be a reference to the baptism and the eucharist, and nothing more. In contrast to Bultmann, Lightfoot maintained that, although the symbolism was indeed intended, the passage is esential to the integrity of John's Gospel and is therefore unlikely to be a redaction.

Tuomas Rasimus (*[Paradise Reconsidered in Gnostic Mythmaking](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=pxWwCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq=%22blood%20and%20water%22%20redaction&source=bl&ots=ACqx_E8HiK&sig=-oz07uHnEkOU9qnWtVwP289kVR4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzqsK52bHKAhVHHKYKHSGOAOgQ6AEIPTAI#v=onepage&q=%22blood%20and%20water%22%20redaction&f=false)*, page 263) refers to the Johannine schism (*) and suggests that *John* was redacted to remove any apparent docetism and affirm Christ's humanity. The centrist party, whose version of the Johannine documents have come down to us, could have had the references to blood and water inserted in order to  undermine the claims of the docetist schismatics.

Burton L. Mack says, in *[Who Wrote the New Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060655186)*, page 219, that John 19:35 (`And he that saw it bare record, and his record is true: and he knoweth that he saith true, that ye might believe`) is an obvious insertion. Perhaps this strengthens to case for 19:34B to be an insertion as well.

***Footnote***

---

(*) Some scholars have suggested that the Johannine epistles were written in response to a schism in the Johannine community, which occurred shortly after the Gospel was written.